How to color text matching some regular expressions in the terminal output
I am running a task that prints output to the VS Code terminal.
The task producing errors in following format:

Error-[SOME_ID] Some error title

Error body


For example, I want to color the first line matching "Error-[\w+].*" in red
How can this be done?

I don't know about colouring, but if problem diagnostics work for you, see "problem matchers".

I'm familiar with the problem matchers approach, and still need a convenient look and feel on the terminal output. thanks!

You could pipe through a command that matches text patterns and wraps with ANSI escape codes for colouring.
